# Increase click reaction time WP8 HTML5?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I am developing a game in HTML5 and have created a Windows Phone 8 HTML5 containter for it. The only problem I am having is with touch.

First there is a small circle that appears where I click.

Second is there a way to increase how quickly touches are detected?

Finally any way to disable scrolling in the web browser view?

Comment: Assuming you're using JS: 1) Not sure what to do you help you there, maybe it's part of the scrolling?
2) What event(s) are you using? touchstart would be the fastest way to detect events (just like mousedown)... if you use touchend, you have to lift your finger before it is detected
3) Have you done a full prevent default with e.stopPropagation/e.preventBubble, e.returnValue = false, e.cancel = true and returning false? (sorry, don't remember which are IE-specific)

Comment: I am actually using an engine for the HTML5 part of the game. So I don't have deep access to certain events. I am using the fastest available touch that I tried from my testing. Just was wondering if it had something to do with the browser on WP8?

Comment: I don't really know specifics to WP8, unfortunately. I know JS inside and out, so figured I'd just post some basics... It might help other people who may know more if you'd edit your post to include details like what engine you're using, what method you're using to detect touch, what programming language(s) you're using, etc. Sorry I can't be more help!